# OpenGL: What is the fastest way to paint hex maps?

Tags: opengl, hexagonal-tiles

I want to paint a hex map with each hex a (potentially) different color.  The shared border is black and the interior is a solid color.  If I want to paint a 1920x1080 display, how can I do this the fastest way with OpenGL?

See the image below for a sample hex (blown up for clarity).  The color of the hex won't necessarily be the same as any of the surrounding hexes.

[image: Sample Hex With Black Border]

Comment: How often will the hexes change color ?

Comment: @Bahbar: the color of the hex will change once per state change.  The state can change based on several criteria: touch from user, AI moving things, etc.  My main concern is to NOT have a lag if the AI changes a lot of hexes (possibly the whole screen).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `TRIANGLE_FAN` would work quite well, since a hex is convex.

Fill the entire area with the border color, then render each hex as a `TRIANGLE_FAN` leaving a gap between adjacent hexes where the border color can show through.

Comment: Sorry, I put my comment in the wrong place.  Here it is again for completeness.                                                       I read up on triangle_fans and I understand the concept. However, does it work with my particular border scheme. Take a look at the black pixels in the picture. Also, your picture doesn't have a straight line border, but an anti-aliased (or so it seems) border. How do these play into things?

Comment: @No One: I didn't provide a picture.  Anyway, if `GL_SMOOTH` is disabled, you should get pure colors as in your picture.  If enabled, edges will be anti-aliased.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: I meant the original picture in my post.  Notice that the black border lines are not contiguous, rather small line segments.

Comment: @No One: I just told you, you can control that with `GL_SMOOTH`.  Shouldn't matter whether you are drawing lines or, as I suggested, leaving gaps between the hexes and allowing a solid background to show through.  `glDisable(GL_SMOOTH);` will get you the aliased lines you are looking for.

Comment: @No One in Particular: Are you saying you actually *want* the aliased lines?